# Frustrating issue with CORRECTLY assigning color, using ifelse in mycol argument, to highlight line in xyplot spaghetti plot

Tags: r, if-statement, label, data-visualization, linegraph

I am trying to brightly color one line in my spaghetti plot to distinguish it from the others (which other lines are grey). Using a simple ifelse statement in the color argument (or creating a separate variable - tried both) should do the trick, but this is not aligning with the correct identifying country labels. Conditioning on country label **does** correctly identify specific countries of interest when plotting, or when labeling. However, when using this in an ifelse statement with the **col =** argument, the highlighted line gets mixed up with the incorrect country label. I'm wondering if anyone has come across this issue before. Thanks very much in advance for any insights. Reprex included below.

````
Data <- data.frame(
    score = round(runif(25,0,1), 2), 
    label = c("ZAF", "MEX", "URY", "ROU", "CHL","ZAF", "MEX", "URY", "ROU", "CHL","ZAF", "MEX", "URY", "ROU", "CHL","ZAF", "MEX", "URY", "ROU", "CHL","ZAF", "MEX", "URY", "ROU", "CHL"), 
    year = c(2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2001, 2001, 2001,2001,2001, 2002, 2002,2002,2002,2002,2003,2003,2003,2003,2003,2004,2004,2004,2004,2004))

library(lattice)
library(directlabels)

## just plotting ZAF label - this is what it should look like
xyplot(Data$score[Data$label == "ZAF"] ~ Data$year[Data$label == "ZAF"], type = "l", xlab = "Year", ylab = "Democracy Score", col = ifelse(Data$label == "ZAF", "red", "grey"))

## now plotting all labels - highlights the wrong label in red, should still highlight ZAF 
myplot <- xyplot(Data$score ~ Data$year, group = Data$label, type = "l", xlab = "Year", ylab = "Democracy Score", col = ifelse(Data$label == "ZAF", "red", "grey"))
direct.label(myplot)```
````

Comment: Your code is working. It shows 4 grey and one red line.

Comment: @MarBlo the issue is that it is highlighting the WRONG red line. I am telling it in the col = argument that the line should be red when label == "ZAF," but when I run the myplot command it highlights the line with the "CHL" label. Please let me know if you are able to resolve this issue, thanks.

Comment: I have added an answer in ggplot as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked [here](https://homerhanumat.github.io/tigerstats/xyplot.html) and found that you can set `par.settings`. But you have to do this in order, and label is ordered alphabetically. So as CHL comes first in your labels, its color needs to be first in the col-vector. Please change the color to your taste.

```r
set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(
  score = round(runif(25,0,1), 2), 
  label = c("ZAF", "MEX", "URY", "ROU", "CHL","ZAF", "MEX", "URY", "ROU", "CHL","ZAF", "MEX", "URY", "ROU", "CHL","ZAF", "MEX", "URY", "ROU", "CHL","ZAF", "MEX", "URY", "ROU", "CHL"), 
  year = c(2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2001, 2001, 2001,2001,2001, 2002, 2002,2002,2002,2002,2003,2003,2003,2003,2003,2004,2004,2004,2004,2004))

library(lattice)
library(directlabels)

myplot <- xyplot(score ~ year, 
                 data = df,
                 group = label, 
                 auto.key = T,
                 type = "l", 
                 xlab = "Year", ylab = "Democracy Score", 
                 par.settings = list(
                   superpose.symbol = list(col = c("red","blue","blue","blue","blue"),pch = 19),
                   superpose.line = list(col = c("red","blue","blue","blue","blue"),lwd = 2))
            )

print(direct.label(myplot))
```

[image]

---

**Addition in ggplot**

Here is an example of how this can be done in `ggplot`. This is just one of many ways to to this. Another way would be to use the package `gghighlight`.

```r
set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(
  score = round(runif(25,0,1), 2), 
  label = c("ZAF", "MEX", "URY", "ROU", "CHL","ZAF", "MEX", "URY", "ROU", "CHL","ZAF", "MEX", "URY", "ROU", "CHL","ZAF", "MEX", "URY", "ROU", "CHL","ZAF", "MEX", "URY", "ROU", "CHL"), 
  year = c(2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2001, 2001, 2001,2001,2001, 2002, 2002,2002,2002,2002,2003,2003,2003,2003,2003,2004,2004,2004,2004,2004))


# Here is one way to do this with ggplot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=year, y= score, group = label)) +
  geom_line(color='lightgrey')+
  geom_line(data = df[df$label=='CHL',], color = 'red') +
  geom_text(data = df[df$year == 2000,],mapping =aes(x=1999.5,label=label),color='lightgrey')+
  geom_text(data = df[df$year == 2000 & df$label=='CHL',],mapping =aes(x=1999.5,label=label),color='red')+
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = 'none')
```

[image]